# How to set up webhook in Pardot?

Tags: salesforce, webhooks, pardot

I want to send POST request from Pardot to our website when a Prospect is opt out from a list. We had our application integrated with mailchimp before and in mailchimp it is easy to set up webhook on certain activity like subscribe, unsubscribe etc.. Now we moved to Pardot and I am trying to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

Pardot does not currently support web hooks. You need to regularly query (poll) for the data you are interested in getting.